# How to get POST data from multidimensional array input using Codeigniter when array index is not in English characters?

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I have this snip of code:

```
<?PHP
if ($_POST)
{
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($_POST["test"]);
    echo "</pre>";
}
?>

<form method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="test[تهران][]" value="first">
    <input type="text" name="test[تهران][]" value="second">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

and when I click the submit button, the output is:

```
Array
(
    [تهران] => Array
        (
            [0] => first
            [1] => second
        )

)
```

I have converted this snip of code to Codeigniter controller (Test.php) like this:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Test extends CI_Controller {
    public function index()
    {
        if ($_POST)
        {
            echo "<pre>";
            print_r($_POST["test"]);
            echo "</pre>";
        }

        echo '<form method="POST">
                <input type="text" name="test[تهران][]" value="first">
                <input type="text" name="test[تهران][]" value="second">
                <input type="submit">
            </form>';
    }
}
```

but it is the output of the code after click on the submit button:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => first
            [1] => second
        )

)
```

I have changed the array indexes of Presian to English like this:

```
<input type="text" name="test[tehran][]" value="first">
<input type="text" name="test[tehran][]" value="second">
```

and the output is working again:

```
Array
(
    [tehran] => Array
        (
            [0] => first
            [1] => second
        )

)
```

but for some reasons I need to use Persian language. then can you please guide me how I can solve this problem with Persian language in Codeigniter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take a look at `_clean_input_keys()` in `system/core/Input.php`

The default regular expression

```
preg_match("/^[a-z0-9:_\/-]+$/i", $str)
```

would not work for Persian characters.

You could try replacing that with:

```
preg_match("/^[آ ا ب پ ت ث ج چ ح خ د ذ ر ز ژ س ش ص ض ط ظ ع غ ف ق ک گ ل م ن و ه ی]+$/i", $str))
```

Or testing by commenting that check out.

Comment: Thank you so much
It's working :)
to have English and Persian, it's the final change:
preg_match('/^[a-z0-9:_\/|-آ ا ب پ ت ث ج چ ح خ د ذ ر ز ژ س ش ص ض ط ظ ع غ ف ق ک گ ل م ن و ه ی]+$/i', $str)